# Is it incorrect to create a large message-handler lookup table?

Tags: python, design-patterns, event-handling

I have a queue that I'm pushing messages to.  The messages have a unique integer ID.  I basically have something that looks like this:

```
#-------------------------
#Message handlers
#-------------------------
def noOperation():
    print "Do nothing"

def msgHandler1():
    print "Handling message with ID = 1"

def msgHandler2():
    print "Handling message with ID = 2"

#-------------------------
#Message lookup table
#-------------------------
lookupTable = {
    0: noOperation,
    1: msgHandler1,
    2: msgHandler2
    #...etc...
}

#-------------------------
#Message processing
#-------------------------
while threadActive:
    message = buffer.get(block=True)
    if message:
        lookupTable[message.id]()
```

My question is:  Is there a more efficient way to do this sort of thing?  If I have a few dozen message types (or, for the sake of argument, lets say that the number of message types is unbounded, and will continue to grow over time), then my lookup table is going to get pretty big.  Maybe this isn't really a problem - I'm not sure...it just somehow feels wrong to be creating this big table that maps to dozens of message handler methods.  Is this sort of thing a well known problem with a well-defined solution?  Are there any patterns that touch on this?

Comment: Are the message IDs consecutive? ie. 0-100 or are there big gaps?

Comment: @MartinEvans - they are consecutive

Comment: how much the handlers are similar ?

Comment: @XavierCombelle - They will often do completely different things, so not very similar.

Comment: what you mean by efficient ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is the best way. The closest design pattern would be the [command pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). And this is more or less how you'd implement it in python. I am not worried that your lookup table will be too big. The only change I will recommend in your code is the following

```
if message.id in lookupTable:
    lookupTable[message.id]()
else:
    print "invalid id"
```

That way you can handle the default case in the `else`

Answer (score 0):

If your IDs are consecutive, it would be better to use a simple list which can be accessed directly. This avoids having to do a dictionary lookup.

```
lookupTable = [
    noOperation,        # index 0
    msgHandler1,        # index 1
    msgHandler2         # index 2 etc
    ]

while threadActive:
    message = buffer.get(block=True)
    if message:
        try:
            lookupTable[message.id]()
        except IndexError:
            print 'unknown id {}'.format(message.id)
```

It is also better in Python to try to use the index and catch the exception instead of first testing for it being valid. This will result in much faster code. Also, do not use `in` as this will do a linear search of your array.

Comment: as written lookupTable is a set not a list

Comment: Indeed, I have fixed it.

Comment: This is probably a good idea in case the lookup table grows to be quite large, however, for my purpose - the number of handles will be pretty small (almost guaranteed to be less than 100) and the performance won't be an issue.  The nature of my question was more towards the design of the solution.  From what I'm seeing, having a lookup table or an array should be fine though.

Comment: An array lookup is better for ANY size, a dictionary lookup will always be slower. In your case the ID maps perfectly to an array. A dictionary is better when this is not the case.